# OpenCart - правка футера

Tags: php, opencart

Хочу добавить ссылку в футер.

В файле /catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/common/footer.tpl 
Для футера указан код:

```
<div id="footer">

    <?php echo $this->journal2->settings->get('config_footer_menu'); ?>

</div>
```

Где может быть файл шаблона, в котором остальная разметка футера?

Comment: Вы уверены, что футер не редактируется из Панели администратора? Код ссылается на переменную.

Comment: @AntonBogomolov, похоже на это. Но в админке такого интерфейса не вижу ни в одном из разделов. Скриншот https://gyazo.com/25c789fc60f7bd24455fbe8c81b9c8e9. Может я его не там ищу?

Comment: В шаблоне есть блок footer_menu? Посмотрите модули HTML в панеле управления

Comment: @AntonBogomolov, Решил вопрос. Футер редактируется через сторонний модуль. Т.е. интерфейс можно найти в Панели Администратора > Модули > Модули. Спасибо за подсказку. Поставил плюсы в карму.

Answer (score 0):

Футер редактируется через модули HTML, расположенный в указанном в переменной блоке шаблона.